# Number of times pair has matching variable values

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame with an `id` variable, a `date` variable, and another variable `x` (e.g. `df` below). For each pair of values of `x`, I want to know how many times they share the same value for both `id` and `date`. So, the results should look something like those shown below. `a` and `b` are "together" 2 times, and `a` and `c` are "together" 1 time (where together means sharing same `id` and `date`). Speed is somewhat important.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,1,1), date = c(rep(1,4),2,2), 
                 x = c('a','b','a','c','a','b'))
  id date var
1  1    1   a
2  1    1   b
3  2    1   a
4  2    1   c
5  1    2   a
6  1    2   b

result <- data.frame(x1= c('a','a'), x2= c('b','c'), times.together = 2:1)

  var1 var2 times.together
1    a    b              2
2    a    c              1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,1,1), 
                 date = c(rep(1,4),2,2), 
                 x = c('a','b','a','c','a','b'))
```

#### solution

Uses a combination of base R and `tidyverse` verbs

```
myfun <- function(df) {
            require(tidyverse)
            df1 <- tibble(id=paste(df$id, df$date), x=df$x)
            df2 <- split(df1, df1$id)
            grp <- map_df(df2, ~as.data.frame(matrix(combn(.x$x,2), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=F)) %>%
                       count(V1,V2)
            return(grp)
         }
```

#### Output

```
ans <- myfun(df)

     V1    V2     n
1     a     b     2
2     a     c     1
```

#### More complicated case

```
newdf <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1), 
                    date = c(rep(1,4),2,2,1), 
                    x = c('a','b','a','c','a','b','c'))
```

Note that now `a, b, c` share `id=1 date=1`

```
ans <- myfun(newdf)

     V1    V2     n
1     a     b     2
2     a     c     2
3     b     c     1
```

#### Comparison

```
bouncy <- function(df) {
            require(dplyr)
            newdf %>%
              group_by(id, date) %>%
              summarise(x_list = list(sort(x))) %>% # list of x values
              ungroup() %>% 
              select(x_list) %>% # only select the list
              rowwise() %>% # by each row
              mutate(var1 = x_list[1], var2 = x_list[2]) %>% # extract components of list
              select(-x_list) %>% # remove list
              count(var1, var2) # count the vars
          }

ans <- bouncy(newdf)

    var1   var2     n
1      a      b     2
2      a      c     1
```

**NOTE** that bouncy function **does not return correct answer with more complicated case**

#### Performance

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfun(newdf), bouncy(newdf))

              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      myfun(newdf) 31.72188 32.23807 34.32655 32.70342 34.22985 112.5996   100
     bouncy(newdf) 58.55471 59.41472 61.37818 60.59873 61.60430  78.5788   100
```

**myfun** is about **twice as fast**

Answer (score 3):

We can use the **`dplyr`** package to accomplish this. Note that when we defined `df`, we set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in our call to `data.frame`!

```
library(dplyr)

# grouping by id and date, create a list of the x values
df %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  summarise(x_list = list(sort(x)))-> df2

# unlist the x values into a data.frame
data.frame(
  t(sapply(df2$x_list, function(x) c(x[1], x[2]))),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  -> df3

# count the occurences
df3 %>% count(X1, X2)

     X1    X2     n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1     a     b     2
2     a     c     1
```

This can also be accomplished in fewer intermediate steps as follows:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  summarise(x_list = list(sort(x))) %>% # list of x values
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(x_list) %>% # only select the list
  rowwise() %>% # by each row
  mutate(var1 = x_list[1], var2 = x_list[2]) %>% # extract components of list
  select(-x_list) %>% # remove list
  count(var1, var2) # count the vars

   var1  var2     n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1     a     b     2
2     a     c     1
```

Comment: This is great, much much faster than my naïve for-loop method.